# Does Istio on AWS requires AWS ALB?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks, aws-alb

I will install Istio as a service mesh on AWS EKS. I know that Istio provides its own Ingress Gateway. What I am confused about is: **Do we still need to use AWS ALB or ELB in front of Istio Ingress Gateway?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that Istio will create [a Service for its Ingress Deployment](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/cbd5e811a44c7bac6226b019f1d1810ef5ee45fa/incubator/istio/values.yaml#L110) of type `LoadBalancer`, Kubernetes will take care of provisioning the ELB for you. No need to create it yourself although you could also configure the Service to point to an existing ELB.

*The linked Service is outdated and for ease of reference only. The latest Istio chart is actually [here](http://gcsweb.istio.io/gcs/istio-release/releases/1.5.0/charts/). You should be able to download it and confirm the Service configuration.*